# ¿como pasar un parametro entre dos controladores?

Tags: c#

Resulta que tengo un boton en mi vista, el cual llama a una ventana modal la cual parametizo con el controlador de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-url="@Url.Action("partialViewPrueba", "Date", new { serieDesplegar = @item.rme_codigo})">
```

Quisiera poder hacer la misma accionde pero de manera automatica serieDesplegar = @item.rme_codigo, ya que si no referencio el parametro serieDesplegar = @item.rme_codigo, dado que serieDesplegar me muestra dependiendo del codigo de una "maquina impresora", me dara un error que el codigo es nulo en el metodo de la clase al cual llamo al controlador y no podre devolver el "status"

todo esto va probado mediante web service, los datos que me envia la maquina son 5, me retorna 5 datos entre ellos esta Status, ese dato quiero retornarlo en mi tabla, pero no se como parametizarlo, ya que me devuelve null, lo estuve probando en como llamarlo y me devuelve null, se que si le parametizo automaticamente una serie yo mismo, me retorna bien, la pregunta es, hay manera de parametizar el serieDesplegar con item.rme_codigo automaticamente en la vista, que esta en la misma tabla?, cabe destacar que el dato rme_codigo me lo trae desde la BASE DE DATOS, gracias.

asi llamo el dato Status a la vista, sin parametro claro:

```
    @if (ViewBag.viubag != null)
    { 
            <table class="table">
                <tr>

                    <td>Status</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @ViewBag.viubag[5]
                    </td>

                </tr>


            </table>
}

en el controlador:


   public ActionResult verStatuss(string serieDesplegar)
        {
            string[] holi = new string[6];
            holi = logica.desplegarTabla(serieDesplegar);
            ViewBag.viubag = holi;
            return View(logica.desplegarTabla(serieDesplegar));
        }
```

pd:el metodo desplegarTabla me muestra los 5 datos de la maquina, entre ellos status, por eso retorno como matriz[5] en la vista, el cual es verStatuss, gracias de ante mano, ojalas se haya entendido

Comment: pero en el Url.Action() estas invocando al action partialViewPrueba, del controller Date, ese action verStatuss no aplica en ningun momento, deberias enviar el ViewBag.viabag desde el controller partialViewPrueba

Comment: teniendo tantos nombres tenias que ponerle Date al controller, recomiendo que lo cambies

Comment: Hola Sr.Leandro!, asi es correcto lo que me dices del controlador "Date", lo que quiero hacer es definir: "Vista", "Controlador", new { serieDesplegar = @item.rme_codigo}), pero que se abra automaticamente y me lo muestre en una tabla, si no lo hago por medio de una accion, hay alguna manera de hacerlo?, ya que si serieDesplegar no es igual a rme_codigo, me dara valor nulo (debe tener un codigo para que pueda el controlador recorrer la clase donde esta el metodo)